# Android Studio Compilation error

Tags: ftp, gradle, android-studio

I am using new android studio for my project.
i am getting compilation error.

i am also using two external jar file in my project.

1:-commons-net-3.2.jar
2:-commons-net-3.2-sources.jar

Cant get what goes wrong please help.

following is error message.

> Gradle:  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':FtpSample:compileDebug'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT : this was a workaround available up to Android-Studio 0.2.0**

One thing you can do is deactivate the external build. To do so click on "compiler settings icon".

[image]

Uncheck "Use External build

[image]

And you will see the errors in the console

Comment: I am not looking for error log man
I just want to know why my external jar cause error

Comment: ok... but to fix a compilation error it's often cool to see compiler logs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with some external jar and gradle system .

if your jar file dosent compile then just open

build.gradle--> then edit following code .

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/your jar file')


}
```

i hope this help people with same error